# PHP Intersection of array containing substrings of another one

Tags: php, arrays

I have these 2 arrays:

```
array(
  100 => 'this is some text',
  161 => 'prefix1 : this is some text',
  224 => 'some other text',
  356 => 'prefix2 : some other text',
  // ...
)
```

and

```
array(
  0 => 'prefix1',
  1 => 'prefix2',
  // ...
)
```

The first array should not contain the prefixes, so I would like to identify the errors like this as a result:

```
array(
  161 => 'prefix1 : this is some text',
  356 => 'prefix2 : some other text',
  // ...
)
```

Comment: Don't you have any attempt to show us ...? Two nested loops, `strpos` to check if the current text from the first array starts with the current prefix, and if so, add the text to your error array.

Comment: Related: [Filter array in PHP using keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8841947/2943403)

Comment: @Jib Are your prefix strings "known in advance" or are they supplied by a user (a source other than you)?  Are the prefixes always numbers and letters? Are these "prefixes" always at the start of the searched strings in the array?  Do we need to make "whole word" matches?  In other words, do we need to worry about "prefix1" unintentionally matching "prefix11"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_filter` with `str_contains` like:

```
$a = [
  100 => 'this is some text',
  161 => 'prefix1 : this is some text',
  224 => 'some other text',
  356 => 'prefix2 : some other text',
  ];


$b = ['prefix1','prefix2'];

print_r(array_filter($a, function($a) use ($b){
    foreach($b as $pref){
        if(str_contains($a, $pref)){
            return true;
        }
    }
}));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [161] => prefix1 : this is some text
    [356] => prefix2 : some other text
)
```

Example:

https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/c/c55a9

Reference:

- [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)
- [str_contains](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-contains)

Comment: Check for a prefix would rather warrant `str_starts_with` than `str_contains`.

Comment: @CBroe Yes also, it still seems the same to me since theoretically the prefix is ​​unique and already preset :)

Comment: Yes, but they could have f.e. `this is some text prefix1 foo bar` as one of their input values. `str_contains` will find `prefix1` in there, but if we are actually looking only for texts that are _starting_ with this value, and not just contain it at _any_ arbitrary position, this would be a "false positive" then.

Comment: Yes, I get it, that's why I said _theoretically the prefix is ​​unique_ meaning in the sentence